# Mongoose findOne() returns null on one specific object property query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to search a document in a mongodb collection using mongoose's findOne() property. The schema is as follows:

**The schema for a user's address**

```
const AddressSchema = new Schema({
  houseNumber: { 
    type: String, 
    required: true },
  street: { 
    type: String, 
    required: true },
  barangay: { 
    type: String, 
    required: true },
  city: { 
    type: String, 
    required: true },
  province: { 
    type: String, 
    required: true },
  zipCode: { 
    type: Number, 
    required: true },
})
```

**User Collection**

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  patientID: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  sex: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  birthdate: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  },
  bloodType: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  address: {
    type: AddressSchema,
    required: true
  }
})
```

**And the code that processes the query:**

```
static async fetchUserFiles(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params.id);
    const userData = await User.findOne({ patientID: req.params.id});
}
```

Here's the URL if this would help:

```
router.route("/user/files/:id")
  .get(checkIfAuthenticated, FileHandler.fetchUserFiles)
```

The problem is that, when I try to search a user by its username, like `await User.findOne({username: 'johnsmith'})`, it works perfectly. However, when the above code is executed, the function returns `null`. I have checked if I'm giving the right type of query, but still it gives `null`. Upon observation, I also tried searching for other document fields like `firstName` and `lastName`, it works fine. It only throws null when I'm trying to search by `patientID`.

Any leads highly appreciated!

Comment: Make sure your field is actually named `patientID` and not `patientId` in database.

Comment: I have already checked that also. It is indeed `patientID`

Comment: Could your `req.params.id` contain characters that are URL encoded or escaped by express?

Comment: can you turn on the mongo debug ? so we can see the mongodb operation

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if patientId is of type ObjectId and if the value that you are trying to search for is also of type ObjectId. Sometimes the cast can cause an issue